# Joining items in two lists to a string expression

Tags: python, string-concatenation

I am trying to make a category-image using an input image and values in two lists using a simple expression.

I have two lists such that:

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to write an expression similar to:

```
(value < 100)?1:0 | (value < 200)?2:0 | (value < 300)?3:0 | (value < 400)?4:0 | (value < 500)?5:0
```

So that I end up with an image where all values in an input image < 100 are given a new value of 1, and so on.

I understand I could write it as Ive written it above, but I need to do this multiple times and the lengths of the lists change each time.

Is there a way of doing this with .join()?

Comment: Are you sure that those values you're ORing in shouldn't be 1, 2, 4, 8, 16?

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to join using `.join()` ?

Comment: In your sample code, an input of 100 and 200 will both give an output of 7, and an input of 300 and 400 will both give an output of 5. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Ah, I can see that now. I wanted the values below 100 to just have a value of 1 and not be cumulative. I assume Il have to use a range for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I can make from your query, I think you want to generate the expression using the two lists, if it is so then following logic should work (Hope my assumption doesn't turn out wrong):

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

out_expr = ''
for i in range(len(A)):
    out_expr = out_expr + '(value < ' + str(A[i]) + ')?' + str(B[i]) + ':0 | '

out_expr = out_expr[:-2]
print out_expr
```

Comment: This worked! I needed to create an empty list and append each expression to it before joining them up into one large expression! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for to this

```
>>> A = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
>>> B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> x=222
>>> for size,cat in zip(A,B):
...    if x<size:
...        print cat
...        break
... 
3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer one-liners you can use this:

```
A = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
B = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

' | '.join('(value < {0})?{1}:0'.format(*data) for data in zip(A, B))
```